# Use of unresolved identifier?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am getting `Use of unresolved identifier "Rule"` in four different spots.
At `var rules`, `let rule1`, `let rule2` and `let rule3`.
What am I doing wrong?

```
class RulesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var rules = [Rule]()
    let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadRulesData()
    }

    func loadRulesData() {
        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "card1")!
        let rule1 = Rule(name: "Waterfall", photo: photo1, description: "Every player begins drinking, starting with the player who drew the card and continuing in the direction of play. No one can stop drinking until the player before them does.")!

        let photo2 = UIImage(named: "card2")!
        let rule2 = Rule(name: "You", photo: photo2, description: "Player picks someone to drink.")!

        let photo3 = UIImage(named: "card3")!
        let rule3 = Rule(name: "Me", photo: photo3, description: "Player drinks.")!

        rules += [rule1, rule2, rule3] 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the class or structure `Rule` defined?

Comment: If `Rule` is an objective-C class you must import it in your bridging header. Otherwise, check the target to which the `Rule` class is added is it the same as the main one.

Comment: Rule is an empty array.

Comment: No, `Rule` is a type. `rules` is an empty array.

Comment: Have you copied this code from somewhere, or have you written it yourself?

Comment: I was following a tutorial with interpretation, but I added a class in another file called "Rule" and now it seems to be working. thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

If `Rule` is defined in a framework, it must be marked as `public` for you to use it.
If it is defined in the same module, it has to be marked as `internal` (which Swift does implicitly) or `public`.

I would assume, that `Rule` is defined in the same module. Therefore it might help to restart Xcode.
Without further information, it's hard to say what the problem is though.

#### Update:

So, I assume your project looks something like this:

[image: Project]

In `Rule.swift` (or whichever file in the project) you must have defined the type `Rule`. For example it could look like this:

[image: Rule.swift]

If you have not defined the type `Rule`, you may want to read the [Swift Programming Language Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/), before continuing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying - I want to declare an empty array and then fill it with the information coded below it. so in the end there should be a total of 3 items in my array - [rule1, rule2, rule3]. Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: @C.Kelly you need to create a struct or class (class would need also required initialisers) called Rule with 3 properties before creating an empty array.